# How is inequality/approximation obtained?

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, approximation

I am reading on combinatorics - probabilistic methods.

In one particular problem I came across the inequality

$$\binom{n}{k}(1-2^{-k})^{n-k} < n^k e^{-(n-k)2^{-k}}$$

I understand that $\binom{n}{k} < n^k$ but don't know why the entire inequality holds.

Thank you.

Comment: Mr. Stirling is your best friend